# How do I display a wordpress page content?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I know this is really simple but it just isn't coming to me for some reason and google isn't helping me today.

I want to output the pages content, how do I do that?

I thought it was this:

```
<?php echo the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: Most wordpress functions only work correctly if you're inside "The Loop", http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop, especially if you're trying to display content

Comment: Also, you don't need the "echo". the_content() echoes implicitly.

Comment: These answers got the page content for me - all look useful - (using the page ID as the post) No need to mess around with the loop or the query - put it above the loop https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101823/get-the-content-of-a-specific-page-by-id/297097#297097  Simplest answer was `$post   = get_post( 42 );

$output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

echo $output;`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

@Marc B Thanks for the comment. Helped me discover this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it display the content of all the posts but not the current page.

Comment: This works. However, why is it that the PHP community loves to use unnecessary amounts of php tags? It is really confusing to read, and there is no need for it. I have posted a rework of this answer with cleaner syntax if anyone is interested. Not being a hater, as I am going to upvote this one as the answer.

Answer (score 32):

This is more concise:

```
<?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID); ?>
```

and this even more:

```
<?= get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was harder to find than expected.

Comment: Last one works only if you have enable PHP shortcodes

Comment: While the usual `the_content()` is correct, in some custom post templates what you suggest is much better. Doesn't need the `wp_query_reset`. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

@Sydney Try putting wp_reset_query() before you call the loop.
This will display the content of your page.

```
<?php
    wp_reset_query(); // necessary to reset query
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>
```

EDIT: Try this if you have some other loops that you previously ran.
Place wp_reset_query(); where you find it most suitable, but before you call this loop.

Answer (score 9):

For people that don't like horrible looking code with php tags blasted everywhere...

```
<?php
if (have_posts()):
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
  endwhile;
else:
  echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just put this code in your content div

```
<?php
// TO SHOW THE PAGE CONTENTS
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <!--Because the_content() works only inside a WP Loop -->
        <div class="entry-content-page">
            <?php the_content(); ?> <!-- Page Content -->
        </div><!-- .entry-content-page -->

    <?php
endwhile; //resetting the page loop
wp_reset_query(); //resetting the page query
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Page content **can be displayed easily** and perfectly **this way:**

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>                        
      <?php the_content(); ?>          
      <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>                   
      <?php else : ?>                       
        <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found'); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note:**

In terms of displaying content - 
**i)** comments_template() function is an optional use if you need to enable commenting with different functionality.

**ii)** _e() function is also optional but more meaningful & effective than just showing text through `<p>`. while preferred stylized 404.php can be created to be redirected.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding this simple php code block

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_content();
      endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>!Sorry no posts here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

"The Loop" is bad practice.  WordPress should have never implemented it, and it should be deprecated at this point.  It is not good to use random functions that rely on and modify the global state.  Here is the best alternative I have found:

```
<?php
    $post = get_queried_object();
?>
<div>
    <?php echo do_shortcode(apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content)); ?>
</div>
```