# Wordpress - importing dynamic page content into a custom field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm fairly new to Wordpress and am using html5blank as a parent theme for the first time to build a site for a client. I've created the front-end code and have imported all the files into relevant pages & templates. 
Now I'm trying to convert the code which needs to be dynamic across into pages but I'm not sure what the correct php loop code needs to be in the text files.

For example, this is the code on my home page which needs to be dynamic -

**front-page.php**

```
     <section id="welcome">
   <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
            <h4>WELCOME TO FEATURE MEDIA</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="homeimages">
                <div class="four columns"> 
                    <div id="video">      
                        <h3>VIDEO</h3>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/VIDEO.jpg" alt="Video" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="four columns"> 
                    <div id="blog">   
                        <h3>BLOG</h3>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/blog.jpg" alt="blog" >
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="four columns"> 
                    <div id="faq"> 
                        <h3>FAQ</h3>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/faq.jpg" alt="FAQ" >
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

If I want to make the `<h4>` and `<p>` tags content dynamic in the pages section what is the correct code to replace it with in the front.page.php file? I've tried  but nothing happens. Do I need to use add_field? Is it just better to use the ACF plugin? I have quite a few pages for the site so will need to add quite a few dynamic fields. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Hi Daniel, I noticed you answered a similar question to this a while back - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45083223/3521315 do i need the loop to display my content? If so, do I need a loop per page or does it go one time in the index.php file? TIA;)

Answer (score 0):

Is WELCOME TO FEATURE MEDIA page title or?
If it is you could use [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) function within your php file,
that will get you current page title.

And for `<p>` that could be content area of the page so you could use that instead of adding new field. Only if you have a special usage for content are on that page instead of that `<p>` then I'd suggest using ACF.

To get page content you could us `the_content();` function.

And if you need to add extra fields ACF is perfect choice.
You can prevent default content editor, add as many fields you want, limit those field only to specific template etc.

Comment: How do I make the entire page dynamic, so I need a loop for that?

Comment: If you want it dynamic completely I suggest building ACF for this template. For data that you showed up there it doesn't look to me like you need loop( ACF Repeater Field ). All you need would add is like 8 fields to cater what you have there. Easiest thing to do is to check https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ if you need loop you can use repeater field from ACF. There's an example of how to do it on their page as well.